# hide column in bootstrap on mobile phone

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a site with 2 columns and i want to hide one of the columns when the site is viewed on a mobile.  I know you can use the hidden_phone class and set the column class to 99% or whatever it is using a screen size media query but im wondering if this is the correct way of doing it.  Is there a better way or a more correct way

```
<div class="container>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="span8">some content</div>
  <div class="span4 hidden-phone">some content</div>
 </div>
</div> 

@media (max-width: someresolution){
 .span8{
  width:99.3214534%;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Yes, this is actually the approach twitter bootstrap uses. Have a look at [the source code of their grid system](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/grid.less).

The hidden-phone, ... classes (these have been renamed to **hidden-xs**, .. in version 3) work by just setting the "display" attribute to "none" or "block" depending on the current media query. Have a look at their [responsive-utilities](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-utilities.less) and  [mixins](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/less/mixins.less) and look for the text 'responsive-visibility' if you want the full details.

While this is 'less' and not 'css', it should be readable. If you're curious what 'less' is, visit the website at [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/)